# TSQL Create / Alter Stored Procedure from script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure that I need to add to a SQL script for a product update.

I have tried converting it to use `sp_executesql` but I get errors around quotes when I try to run it. I'm not sure what the issue is in this case. Any idea what I am missing?

Original stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spPortalAttachmentLookupDatabases
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #tmpDatabases
    (
        DatabaseName nvarchar(255)
    )

    EXEC sp_Msforeachdb 'use [?];INSERT INTO #tmpDatabases 
                                SELECT ''?'' AS DatabaseName
                                    FROM sys.columns c
                                        inner join sys.objects  o on c.object_id=o.object_id
                                    WHERE ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''model'',''test'',''ReportServer'') AND o.Name = ''AI00'' AND c.Name = ''LookupGuid''
                                    ORDER BY o.name,c.column_id'
    SELECT * FROM #tmpDatabases

    DROP TABLE #tmpDatabases
END
GO

DROP PROCEDURE spPortalAttachmentLookupDatabases
```

Script:

```
DECLARE @SQLCmd as nvarchar(max)
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[spPortalAttachmentLookupDatabases]    Script Date: 14/07/2014 09:16:16 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'spPortalAttachmentLookupDatabases') AND type IN ( N'P', N'PC' ) ) 
    SET @SQLCmd = '
CREATE PROCEDURE spPortalAttachmentLookupDatabases
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #tmpDatabases
    (
        DatabaseName nvarchar(255)
    )

    EXEC sp_Msforeachdb ''''INSERT INTO #tmpDatabases 
                                SELECT ''?'' AS DatabaseName
                                    FROM sys.columns c
                                        inner join sys.objects  o on c.object_id=o.object_id
                                    WHERE ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''model'',''test'',''ReportServer'') AND o.Name = ''AI00'' AND c.Name = ''LookupGuid''
                                    ORDER BY o.name,c.column_id''''
    SELECT * FROM #tmpDatabases

    DROP TABLE #tmpDatabases'
ELSE
    SET @SQLCmd = '
ALTER PROCEDURE spPortalAttachmentLookupDatabases
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #tmpDatabases
    (
        DatabaseName nvarchar(255)
    )

    EXEC sp_Msforeachdb ''''INSERT INTO #tmpDatabases 
                                SELECT ''?'' AS DatabaseName
                                    FROM sys.columns c
                                        inner join sys.objects  o on c.object_id=o.object_id
                                    WHERE ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''model'',''test'',''ReportServer'') AND o.Name = ''AI00'' AND c.Name = ''LookupGuid''
                                    ORDER BY o.name,c.column_id''''
    SELECT * FROM #tmpDatabases

    DROP TABLE #tmpDatabases'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLCmd
GO
```

**Errors**:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spPortalAttachmentLookupDatabases, Line 130
>   Incorrect syntax near ''.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spPortalAttachmentLookupDatabases, Line 133
>   Incorrect syntax near '#tmpDatabases'.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server Management Studio you can always use it to generate the script  for the procedure with the options "DROP AND CREATE" and "IF NOT EXISTS"

Comment: @RdPC That would not work as the problem I have is using the string concatenation when using sp_executesql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a syntax error. Try it now:

```
DECLARE @SQLCmd as nvarchar(max)

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[spPortalAttachmentLookupDatabases]    Script Date: 14/07/2014 09:16:16 ******/

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'spPortalAttachmentLookupDatabases') AND type IN ( N'P', N'PC' ) )

    SET @SQLCmd = '

CREATE PROCEDURE spPortalAttachmentLookupDatabases
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #tmpDatabases
    (
        DatabaseName nvarchar(255)
    )

    EXEC sp_Msforeachdb ''INSERT INTO #tmpDatabases
                                SELECT  ''''?'''' AS DatabaseName
                                    FROM sys.columns c
                                        inner join sys.objects  o on c.object_id=o.object_id
                                    WHERE ''''?'''' NOT IN (''''master'''',''''msdb'''',''''tempdb'''',''''model'''',''''test'''',''''ReportServer'''') 
                                    AND o.Name = ''''AI00'''' AND c.Name = ''''LookupGuid''''
                                    ORDER BY o.name,c.column_id''
    SELECT * FROM #tmpDatabases
    DROP TABLE #tmpDatabases

    END'

ELSE
    SET @SQLCmd = '

ALTER PROCEDURE spPortalAttachmentLookupDatabases
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #tmpDatabases
    (
       DatabaseName nvarchar(255)
    )

    EXEC sp_Msforeachdb ''INSERT INTO #tmpDatabases
                                SELECT ''''?'''' AS DatabaseName
                                    FROM sys.columns c
                                        inner join sys.objects  o on c.object_id=o.object_id
                                    WHERE ''''?'''' NOT IN (''''master'''',''''msdb'''',''''tempdb'''',''''model'''',''''test'''',''''ReportServer'''') 
                                    AND o.Name = ''''AI00'''' AND c.Name = ''''LookupGuid''''
                                    ORDER BY o.name,c.column_id''
    SELECT * FROM #tmpDatabases
    DROP TABLE #tmpDatabases

    END'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLCmd
GO
```

Comment: Your updated edit does not work. There is no closing quote after the order by

Comment: The result of that query just returns ?